# PHP null coalesce + ternary operators strange behavior

Tags: php, ternary-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I'm facing unexpected behavior when using new PHP7 null coalesce operator with ternary operator.

Concrete situation(dummy code):

```
function a()
{
    $a = 1;
    $b = 2;
    return $b ?? (false)?$a:$b;
}

var_dump(a());
```

The result is int(1).

Can anybody explain me why?

Comment: For the sake of my own sanity and any future coders using my code, I always explicitly use brackets in an expression like this.  I like to state my intention and not rely on precedence or other side effects.

Comment: that is a good point and my bad, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your spaces do not reflect the way php evaluates the expression. Note that the `??` has a [higher precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) than the ternary expression.

You get the result of:

```
($b ?? false) ? $a : $b;
```

Which is `$a` as long as `$b` is not `null` or evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 3):

Examine the statement `return $b ?? (false)?$a:$b;`

This first evaluates `$b ?? (false)` whose result is then passed to `? $a:$b`;

`$b ?? (false)` means give the first `not null and isset` value, which in this case is `$b`

Since `$b = 2`, which is a true-ish value, above expression becomes:

return `($b) ? $a : $b` which returns value of `$a` which is `int(1)`

This whole thing will make better sense if you think of original return statement as:

return `($b ?? (false)) ? $a : $b;`

We dont need to add the additional brackets because `??` is evaluated before `?`

Answer (score 0):

```
return $b ?? (false)?$a:$b; // will return 1

return $b ?? ((false)?$a:$b); // will behave as you wanted
```